# Permutation question (books on shelf)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A set of 3 different Mathematics books, 4 different Physics books, and 2 different English books are arranged on a shelf. If the math textbooks are kept together, then the number of different arrangements possible for the books is

my work:

3 math book: 3!
4 different physics books: 4!
2 different English books: 2!

number of different arrangements is to multiply each = 288
the number of arrangements possible for this book is 288 ways.

Answer (score 2):

Temporarily treat the grouped math books as a single entity.  Then you have seven "entities".  These can be placed in $7!$ orders on the shelf.

Now "break apart" the math entity.  There are $3!$ ways to internally order those math books.

Hence $7! 3! = 30,240$